# Fabric8/JBoss Fuse Creating ssh container creation

Tags: jbossfuse, fabric8

I'm trying to create a new SSH container to an existing fabric and It was successfully created using this command:

```
fabric:container-create-ssh --proxy-uri http://"root-container":8181/maven/download/ --jvm-opts "-Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx2014m -Djavax.net.debug=ssl"  --path /app/testing/ --host "testIP" --private-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa --profile default --profile anotherprofile --resolver localhostname --zookeeper-password "zookeepr pass" testing-container
```

The problem is that once i created this new container all the existing ssh container changes their maven download/upload proxy to the above container IP
so instead of using `http://"currentroot":8181/maven/download/` to `http://testIP:8181/maven/download/`

i tried a lot to change the maven proxy from the `"root-container"` fabric profile and default profile but still couldn't reach a solution? 
Is there a missing step that i should take to solve this issue in adding a new ssh container without updating the existing maven repo?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is `anotherprofile`
http://host:port/maven/download/ URIs are registered in Zookeeper registry that's used by fabric environment.

`fabric-maven-proxy` feature, which is declared in `fabric` profile is the feature that's responsible for starting a maven proxy inside any container that has this feature/profile installed. Please check if your new container has this feature installed. Maybe `anotherprofile` has `fabric` profile set as parent?

#### How containers use remote repositories

Each container, when provisioned by fabric-agent, uses `io.fabric8.agent` PID configuration (OSGi configuration admin) and the property is `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories`. It contains a list of remote repositories that are searched for artifacts to install in container.

But there's some dynamism involved too. Fabric agent always searches Zookeeper registry and finds URIs that are registered by other containers that run the above mentioned feature (`fabric-maven-proxy`). All such *discovered* URIs are *prepended* to the list found in `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories` property.

#### How to check maven problem in logs

If you add `karaf` profile to a container, you'll have logging configuration available in `org.ops4j.pax.logging` PID - you can nicely configure it in hawtio. By default, there's commented section like this:

```
# help with identification of maven-related problems with fabric-maven
#log4j.logger.org.eclipse.aether = TRACE
#log4j.logger.org.apache.http.headers = DEBUG
#log4j.logger.io.fabric8.maven.util = TRACE
#log4j.logger.io.fabric8.maven.url = TRACE
#log4j.logger.io.fabric8.agent.download = DEBUG
```

You can uncomment these to see (much) more information about how maven repositories are used.

Comment: the "anotherprofile" in the above command is just a business related profile that doesn't not have configuration for the maven proxy. and even creating the new ssh-container with just the default profile also changes all the fabric maven proxy to point to the newly created ssh-container.

Comment: And If the maven URL is configured in the ZooKeeper registry do u think there is a way to change this information back to the correct URL?